# How to record and run the script in JMeter for multiple users doing multiple navigations

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

I am new to JMeter.
My requirement is as follow:

I wanted to check the performance of my web application when two user logged in same time and doing different actions/navigation after logged in.

I want to know how to record and run it.

1. In each thread group I have put 2-2 users with 0 ramp time and 1
   loop
2. In each recording controller I have configured different urls
   of same web application.
3. Recording Controller has been chosen as a
   target controller.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to properly record and especially replay the described scenario because JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) is capturing requests as they reach it.

So it's better to record 1st user actions and copy the recording under 1st [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) then record 2nd user actions and copy the recording under 2nd Thread Group.

If there are some common steps like opening the login page or navigation or logout - you can use [Test Fragments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) to store these common test elements and refer them using [Module Controllers](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller) where required